# how to configure Java EE timers to access same table in a clustered environment

Tags: performance, jakarta-ee, timer, ejb-3.0, timer-jobs

I have an application which contains a Java EE timer that runs on 2 clustered nodes. The task of the timer is to fetch batches of 100  records from a common table (mysql database) and process it. Since the timer runs on both the nodes , both process the same records. So how to configure it properly so that 1st timer can take 1st batch of 100 records and 2nd timer can take the next batch of 100 records.

I have tried putting the pessimistic write lock on the query, and setting the max results to 100 in java code. But it is not good in performance.

Is there any way to handle this scenario with better performance?

Comment: Can you run the timer on only one node?

Comment: @Abhin yes i can run the timer on one node, but that will make other node resources waste. efficient usage of both the nodes, is what i need.

Comment: No;I mean run the timer on only one node. Say node1. When the timer on node1 begins; fetch your batch of 100 records; at the end of which invoke code on node 2 to telling it from where to start the next batch.